# Ionic 3: Read a file line by line, and loop through the return

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, httpclient, readfile

I am working on a script that must fetch SQL queries in a `.sql` file located in ./assets/, to execute those queries on my local DB with Ionic 3. The idea is that I would like to open the file, store every line separately in an array, then loop on that array with a homemade executeSqlQuery() function.

So far, I think I have been able to open the file thanks to httpClient module, but not a lot more... I have been looking at the File module (native), but couldn't get anything done even with a lot of documentation & tests.

Here is what I did, and I don't know how to go from opening './assets/queries.sql' to executeSqlQuery(queries[i]) :

Excerpt of queries.sql :

```
INSERT INTO `attaquesinf` VALUES ('bandaltchagui','circulaire','Bandal Tchagui','Bandal Chagi','Coup de pied circulaire niveau moyen.',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `attaquesinf` VALUES ('dolyotchagui','circulaire','Dolyo Tchagui','Doleo Chagi','Coup de pied circulaire niveau haut.',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `attaquesinf` VALUES ('biteurotchagui','crochet','Biteuro Tchagui','Biteureo Chagi','Coup de pied de l''intérieur vers l''extérieur dans un mouvement de torsion, avec le bol du pied.',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `attaquesinf` VALUES ('nakkattchagui','crochet','Nakkat Tchagui','Nakka Chagi','Coup de pied crochet, frappe avec le talon.',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Excerpt of ExPage.ts :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

export class ExPage {
    infsql: Observable<any>;

    constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.infsql = this.httpClient.get('./asset/queries.sql')
        this.infsql
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log('my data: ', data);
            // ====> How can I use data ??
            // ====> How can I loop through the content and executeSqlQuery(each line) ?
            },
            error => {
            console.log("Error reading config file " + error.message + ", " + error.code);
            });
      }
  };
...
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: What's the value of `data()`? Maybe just data.split('\n') will be enough but idk how Ionic's HttpClient works.

Comment: How can I explore what's in data ? I tried to put {{ data }} between <p></p> in my view, but i don't have anything showing on screen... I will try data.split(\n) as soon as I find what's in it and how to use it, thanks ! :)

Comment: Just `console.log` it

Comment: Where can I read the console log ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution after ...... some hours of testing. I finally opted for `Http.get` method that does the jobs.

In `ExPages.ts` :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
...

export class ExPage {

    requests: Array<{string}>;     //the final array that will contain each line of .sql file
    testtext: string;              //a variable we'll use to test the content of the request
    ...


    constructor(public http: Http) {

        this.http.get('../assets/queries.sql')               //gets the file
                 .map(res => res.text())                      //maps it as text
                 .subscribe(data => {                         //saves the data in our array
                     this.requests = data.split('\n');
                     this.testtext = this.requests[20];
                 })
    }
}
```

In `ExPages.html` :

```
<p>20th SQL query : {{ testtext }}</p>
```

Will display the 21st line of my `assets/queries.sql` file, as the index of our `request` array starts at `0`.

Thanks for your help @millimoose :)

Comment: You should also be able to do it using the new `HttpClient` API: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

I just couldn't get Plunker to work to actually verify if any code I'm thinking of works.